# How can I remove part of a javascript on condition

Tags: javascript

I want to remove some part inside a javascript on condition:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Generate a simple captcha
    function randomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    };
    $('#captchaOperation').html([randomNumber(1, 100), '+', randomNumber(1, 200), '='].join(' '));

    $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        fields: {
            field1: {
                message: 'The field is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }

                }
            },
            field2: {
                message: 'The field is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }

                }
            },     
            captcha: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Wrong answer',
                        callback: function(value, validator) {
                            var items = $('#captchaOperation').html().split(' '), sum = parseInt(items[0]) + parseInt(items[2]);
                            return value == sum;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

On the above script I would like to remove  field1:{................}, For this I used the following codes:

```
if ($field1=0) {
    $(':contains("field1:{.....};")').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html().split("field1:{......},").join(""));
    });
}
```

The code could not remove the desired parts on condition. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: So you want to delete object "field1" in the array "field" when the condition is reached?

Comment: Yes, I want to delete all the field1 portion.

Comment: but where is the object having field1 loaded? In an object or in an element?

Comment: Just dereference the unwanted property `fields.field1 = undefined;` no need to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to options :

```
delete fields.field1;
fields.field1 = undefined;
```

Comment: I have to delete it on load.