# How to set as undefined or delete certain parts

Tags: javascript

I am trying for several hours but could not find the solutions to delete or undefined parts of following codes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Generate a simple captcha
    function randomNumber(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
    };
    $('#captchaOperation').html([randomNumber(1, 100), '+', randomNumber(1, 200), '='].join(' '));

    $('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        fields: {
            field1: {
                message: 'The field is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }

                }
            },
            field2: {
                message: 'The field is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }

                }
            },     
            captcha: {
                validators: {
                    callback: {
                        message: 'Wrong answer',
                        callback: function(value, validator) {
                            var items = $('#captchaOperation').html().split(' '), sum = parseInt(items[0]) + parseInt(items[2]);
                            return value == sum;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

On the above script I would like to remove field1:{................}, For this following will do the job:

```
delete fields.field1; or
fields.field1 = undefined;
```

But I could not understand how to use the codes.

Comment: just take off that code from the script?

Comment: actually with parameter you want to delete??

Comment: Why are you posting same question twice ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34305026/how-can-i-remove-part-of-a-javascript-on-condition

Comment: Sorry for asking same question since my problem yet to be solved.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to store the object in variable:

```
var validation = {
    message: 'This value is not valid',
    fields: {
        field1: {
            message: 'The field is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 30,
                    message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                    message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                }

            }
        },
        field2: {
            message: 'The field is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The field is required and can\'t be empty'
                },
                stringLength: {
                    min: 1,
                    max: 30,
                    message: 'The field must be more than 1 and less than 30 characters long'
                },
                regexp: {
                    regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                    message: 'The field can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                }

            }
        },     
        captcha: {
            validators: {
                callback: {
                    message: 'Wrong answer',
                    callback: function(value, validator) {
                        var items = $('#captchaOperation').html().split(' '), sum = parseInt(items[0]) + parseInt(items[2]);
                        return value == sum;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

then you can delete it:

```
delete validation.fields.field1;
```

Comment: If that solve your problem don't forget to mark the answer.

Comment: now the problem is validation is not working. will you please show it in fiddle so that everything may work fine.

Comment: @rns You need to call `$('#defaultForm').bootstrapValidator(validation);`

Comment: @rns can you provide jsfiddle with working validation I can't seems to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
delete fields['field1'];
```

Comment: this will delete whole **field1**.

Comment: I have tried with this without any result. Please try it in the fiddle.